# Alternative Admin in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, admin

Hello guys I would like to know if there's a way NOT to override Django Admin, but to build your own, with a custom template. I have searched on the internet but there seems to be no answer. I hope there is a person who knows the answer to my question.

Comment: I don't think I know what your question actually is, though. If you want to build your own forms and views, then just do that; I don't see what the admin has to do with anything, if you don't want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-adminsite

As far as I understood you are trying to have nicer view for admin site. If that is the case I suggest to take a look to Mezzanine, it provides nice features:

http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/admin-customization.html